# Problems inherent in ZFS Storage Pool Upgrade to 19.10?

Tags: upgrade, zfs, 19.10, mass-storage

The pool is formatted using a legacy on-disk format.

Is is safe to do a zpool upgrade or will this destroy or corrupt data on 19.10. I've used zfs on Freebsd for years, but new to Ubuntu. loving it so far.

Comment: Is this what you refer to as 'pool'? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/setup-zfs-storage-pool#0

Comment: Yes. with 19.10 I used the option to install it on ZFS. Works great, but when you run the status it tells you that in order to get all features to run  zpool upgrade. I don't want to do that if it is going to cause a problem. but I have looked online and can find nothing current  about this.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT upgrade the `bpool` pool, as that will render your system unbootable. The `bpool` pool was purposely created with a legacy set of features so that grub can read it.

See also this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zfs-linux/+bug/1847389

Comment: Thank you so much. Thats what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

"Do NOT upgrade the bpool pool, as that will render your system unbootable."

This is not true. I have successfully upgraded the pool on two instances (one VM and one laptop). Both still boot just fine.

This was on a fresh Ubuntu Eoan install. Zpool status told me to upgrade, so I did.

Comment: If you upgrade the pool., new features will be enabled. As soon as a write to the pool makes use of one of these features that grub does not understand, you won't be able to boot.